# SIMPLE RSA in C

Tags: c, encryption, rsa

The Task is to write a program that can encrypt and decrypt Messages with RSA.

I began to write it, but just in the beginning the program do not take my e when i want to decide whether it should encrypt (e) or decrypt (d). Where is the mistake?

And how do i have to go on? I think i didn't get the rsa System..

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Simple RSA:
encrypt text using a secure cryptographic function that makes decryption
impossible unless the recipient has the corresponding key for decryption.
 */

unsigned long long int p;
unsigned long long int q;
unsigned long long int N;   // modulus for encryption and decryption
unsigned int e;
unsigned long long int d;
unsigned long long int phi;
unsigned int c;
unsigned int m;
signed int s;
signed int t;
unsigned long long int e_or_d;
int i = 0;

int main () {

/* Ask the user about the numbers N and e */

printf("Enter N: ");
scanf("%u", &N);
getchar();
printf("Enter e: ");
scanf("%u", &e);
getchar();

/* Ask the user if he wants to decrypt or encrypt a message */

while(1) {
printf("Encrypt or Decrypt [e/d]? ");
scanf("%2c", &e_or_d);
getchar();

if(e_or_d != e | d) {

return 0;

}


if(e_or_d = e) {

printf("Enter message: \n");
scanf("%u", &m);
getchar();

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {

N = p*q;
phi = (p-1)*(q-1);

}

if(N < 0) {

return 0;

}

else if(N = 0) {

return 1;

}

else if(N = 1) {

return ?

}

return 0;

}

if(e_or_d = d) {

printf("Enter d: \n");
scanf("%u", &d);
getchar();

return 0;

}
return 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, I may have missunderstood this. But here:

```
if(e_or_d != e | d) {
    return 0;
}
```

this : [`|`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_OR_.22.7C.22) is bitwise OR. I believe what you meant to do is:

```
if ((e_or_d != 'e') && (e_or_d) != 'd'))
    return 0;
```

to check whether the input is char `'e'` or char `'d'`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I forgot the ' and also did the OR in a wrong way, but i don't work although i corrected my mistakes..

Comment: if((e_or_d != 'e') || (e_or_d != 'd')) {

    return 0;

    }


    if(e_or_d = 'e') {

    printf("Enter message: \n");
    scanf("%u", &m);
    getchar();

    for (i = 0; i